# Clearing a List<string> removes all values from Dictionary List of Strings, C#

Tags: c#, string, list, dictionary, streamreader

Trying to read a csv file, and take the first word in the stream, throw it in to a dictionary while the following words get added to a list in that dictionary.

However, I find that (during debugging) when, inside my loop I decide to clear my list, all of the values it had added to the dictionary previously also get cleared. I guess I am mistaken in assuming it makes a copy of the list, it is actually just referencing that same list? Should I be creating a new list with every iteration? Code below:

```
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start() {

    Dictionary<string, List<string>> theDatabase = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    string word;
    string delimStr = ",.:";
    char[] delimiter = delimStr.ToCharArray();
    List<string> theList = new List<string>();


    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("testComma.csv")) {
        while (true) {
            //Begin reading lines
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            //Begin splitting lines, adding to array.
            string[] split2 = line.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            //Loop to hold the first word in the stream
            for(int i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {
                word = split2[i];

                //loop to hold the following words in to list.
                for (int y = 1; y < split2.Length; y++) {
                    theList.Add(split2[y]);
                }

                //Add word/list combo in to the database
                theDatabase.Add(word, theList);

                //clear the list.
                theList.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> pair in theDatabase) {
        string keys;
        List<string> values;

        keys = pair.Key;
        values = pair.Value;
        print(keys + " = " + values);

    }
  }
}
```

The bottom foreach loop is just so I can see the results. Also, any critique is welcome in regards to how this is written, as I'm a beginner.

Comment: yes you need to make a copy of the list and add that to the dictionnary, or create a new list at each iteration of your outer loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're adding the same object to your dictionary.

You can just change :

```
theDatabase.Add(word, theList);
```

To :

```
theDatabase.Add(word, theList.ToList());
```

Method `ToList()` makes shallow copy of your `List<T>`

Comment: I get the following error when I try that:

CS1061 'List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'List<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Fixed it. I didn't have a reference to Linq,

Answer (score 2):

C# is pass by reference.
So, `theList` and the list in your `Dictionary` are the same object.

The simplest solution is to stop clearing your `List` and create a new one every time instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {
    List<string> theList = new List<string>(); // it is in a loop now

    word = split2[i];

    //loop to hold the following words in to list.
    for (int y = 1; y < split2.Length; y++) {
        theList.Add(split2[y]);
    }

    //Add word/list combo in to the database
    theDatabase.Add(word, theList);

    //clear the list.
    //theList.Clear(); - not required anymore
}
```

It is more readable and clear solution: create a list, insert items, paste a list into the dictionary, continue the iteration.
It is also much more performant since there is no `List` clearing - `List<T>.Clear()` is a linear operation, which takes `O(n)` operations.

Comment: Thanks, I was clearing it because I wanted to re-use it without the old entries inside.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as everyone says, lists are reference types. You need to make a copy to avoid the `.Clear()` clearing all the lists.

You could always write your code like this:

```
void Start()
{
    string delimStr = ",.:";
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> theDatabase = 
        File
            .ReadAllLines("testComma.csv")
            .Select(line => line.Split(delimStr.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x.Skip(1).ToList());

    /* foreach here */
}
```

}

This doesn't have the problem with the list references.